# Different description meta tag for each page in wordpress without plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-tags

how to use different `description meta tag` for each page in wordpress.

I have one `header.php` file for all of the theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add different description Meta tags Without using plugin you could create Custom fields in Wordpress and then call them in your `header.php` file

https://wordpress.org/support/article/custom-fields/

Answer (score 1):

Do check the SEO dashboard, Where you can change the description for each pages.

Go through the theme documentation, Every theme has a plugin to change the description.

Or use Google web master tool there are many resources and youtube tutorial which might help you.